# python 5 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use scipy.optimize to solve a quadratic programming.

```
def objFun(vector):
    "input value is a vector parameter"
    return ((vector.transpose()*Q*vector + b.transpose()*vector)[0] + c).item()

def scipy_result():
    init = np.matrix([[1] for i in range(5)])
    res = optimize.minimize(objFun, init, method="CG")
    print("value of x^* is", res.x, '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scipy_result()
```

I don't there is any error in the dimension of multiplication and stuff.

But

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Siyuan Xu\OneDrive - purdue.edu\Purdue Courses\CS 520\programming hw 1\homework 1.py", line 91, in <module>
    scipy_result()

  File "C:\Users\Siyuan Xu\OneDrive - purdue.edu\Purdue Courses\CS 520\programming hw 1\homework 1.py", line 63, in scipy_result
    res = optimize.minimize(objFun, init, method="CG")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 610, in minimize
    return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 1423, in _minimize_cg
    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 261, in _prepare_scalar_function
    sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 76, in __init__
    self._update_fun()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 166, in _update_fun
    self._update_fun_impl()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 73, in update_fun
    self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 70, in fun_wrapped
    return fun(x, *args)

  File "C:\Users\Siyuan Xu\OneDrive - purdue.edu\Purdue Courses\CS 520\programming hw 1\homework 1.py", line 30, in objFun
    return ((vector.transpose()*Q*vector + b.transpose()*vector)[0] + c).item()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 220, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot

ValueError: shapes (1,5) and (1,5) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

I am confused. And I tried. Making input an array (change the obj function as well) and it also does not work. Please help me to see how to fix this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: With `np.matrix`, `*` is matrix multiplication, the `np.dot`.  Use of `np.matrix` is discouraged these days.  Try `init= np.ones((5,1),int)` instead if you need a (5,1) shaped array of 1s.

Comment: It seems still not working.@hpaulj

Comment: If you read `minimize` docs carefully you'll see that the initial value, `x0`, and the function argument, should be a 1d array, e.g. shape `(n,)`.  So the use of `transpose` in your objection is wrong.  Keep track of array dimensions through out your code.

Comment: OK. I am checking the interface. I am using it (numpy.matrix) for other part because it makes other part (gradient descent using exact line search easier) @hpaulj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your problem statement, `Q,b,c` are not defined or described.  But the error makes me suspect that `Q` is a `np.matrix`.

Let's explore a slightly simpler function:

```
In [58]: from scipy import optimize
In [59]: def f(x):
    ...:     print(x, x.shape)
    ...:     Q = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
    ...:     res = x.T*Q*x
    ...:     print(res, res.shape)
    ...:     return res
    ...:
```

It's often a good idea to test the objective function by itself.  `np.minimize` says the initial variable should be 1d, `(n,)` shape, but let's see how various arguments work:

1d (2,) shape:

```
In [60]: f(np.arange(2))
[0 1] (2,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-60-ef04d08d3a6e>", line 1, in <module>
    f(np.arange(2))
  File "<ipython-input-59-ef8f7ef56c80>", line 4, in f
    res = x.T*Q*x
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 218, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

In detail:

```
In [65]: Q=np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [66]: x=np.arange(2)
In [67]: x*Q                    # first matrix product (because of Q)
Out[67]: matrix([[3, 4]])       # (1,2) shape
In [68]: (x*Q)*x                # second product
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-68-94f5369405fc>", line 1, in <module>
    (x*Q)*x
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 218, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

When used with `Q`, `np.matrix(np.arange(2))` produces a `(1,2)` `matrix([[0, 1]])` matrix.

But if `x` starts as (2,1) shape then the double product does work:

```
In [72]: x=np.arange(2)[:,None]
In [73]: (x.T*Q)*x
Out[73]: matrix([[4]])
In [74]: f(x)
[[0]
 [1]] (2, 1)
[[4]] (1, 1)
Out[74]: matrix([[4]])
```

But if I plus that `f` and `x` into `minimize` I get an error, because the (2,1) array has been 'reduced' to (2,)

```
In [76]: optimize.minimize(f, x)
[0. 1.] (2,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Changing `f` to work with 1d array:

```
def f(x):
    print(x, x.shape)
    x = x[:,None]
    Q = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
    res = x.T@Q@x
    print(res, res.shape)
    return res.item()
In [86]: f(np.arange(2))
[0 1] (2,)
[[4]] (1, 1)
Out[86]: 4
```

Now `optimize.minimize(f, np.arange(2))` runs (but doesn't converge).

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix: change your objFun(vector) to:

```
def objFun(vector):
    "input value is a vector parameter"
    vector = np.reshape(vector, (-1, 1))
    return ((vector.transpose()*Q*vector + b.transpose()*vector)[0] + c).item()
```

Comment: Thanks! I no longer use numpy.matrix for anything. I switched everything to np.array for matrix manipulation. Is that the right thing to do now?

Comment: As long as you want vector to be of (n, 1) dimensions in the bottom equation it will still work.

Comment: And if you have modified your code please do update the question.

Comment: I think I solved the question, so should I post my solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Fix would be define everything using np.array

```
def objFun(vector):
    "input value is a column vector parameter"

 
    return ((np.matmul(np.matmul(vector.transpose(),Q),vector) + \
            np.matmul(b.transpose(),vector))[0] + c).item()

def scipy_result():
    vector = np.ones((5,1),int)
    print("This is result of c part")
    res = optimize.minimize(objFun, vector, method="CG")
    print("value of x^* is", res.x.reshape(-1,))
    print("value of f(x^*)", objFun(res.x))
```